# Can't use await at top level of parcel-built browser extension's popup.js

Tags: javascript, async-await, parceljs, web-extension

In a parcel-bundled browser extension, I have set up my popup's HTML to load a script tag with the attribute `type="module"`, like so:

```
// popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Popup</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My web extension</h1>
        <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
// popup.js
import { setNameSpace, getTab } from "./helpers.js"
import { startStore } from "./store.js"

setNameSpace()

const store = startStore()
const state = await store.get()
```

As specified in the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/get-started/tutorial/popup-tabs-manager), this should allow use of the `await` keyword before async funcs at the top level:

```
Tip: You can use top level await by adding type="module" to the script tag.
```

...but popup.js still gives the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

I can get around this by wrapping in a self-invoking async function, but why is this extra workaround needed?

```
// popup.js
...
(async ()=> {
    const store = startStore()
    const state = await store.get()
})()
```

My `package.json`, for reference:

```
{
  "name": "my-web-extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My web extension",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:chrome": "parcel watch src/chrome/manifest.json --dist-dir dist-chrome --host localhost --config @parcel/config-webextension",
    "build:chrome": "parcel build src/chrome/manifest.json --dist-dir dist-chrome --config @parcel/config-webextension",
    "watch:firefox": "parcel watch src/firefox/manifest.json --dist-dir dist-firefox --host localhost --config @parcel/config-webextension",
    "build:firefox": "parcel build src/firefox/manifest.json --dist-dir dist-firefox --config @parcel/config-webextension"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/config-webextension": "^2.10.3",
    "parcel": "^2.10.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: the duplicate doesn't explain the error since top-level await does work in `type="module"` JS - which is apparently the case here. Perhaps chrome web-extensions behave differently (differently being a euphemism for Chrome is broken)